# Apple - App Store Connect - New Tester invalid password

Tags: testing, app-store-connect

I'm trying to setup a sandbox account in Apple's App Store Connect. I've tried every variation of passwords: all lowercase with number and a special character, at least one upper in that same configuration, only alpha characters. No matter I try, it clears the popup indicating it is invalid and allows me to "Invite", but immediately rejects it again. I can't seem to find the password requirements for this anywhere. Suggestions?

Here is a screen shot:
[image: Invalid Password]

Comment: Still not working correctly, Apple for developers is just the worst thing ever.

Answer (score 10):

Looking at the response of the error:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "a55bc8f2-b911-47d6-9b52-c06c1f592310",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID",
    "title" : "The provided entity includes an attribute with an invalid value",
    "detail" : "Die E-Mail-Adresse wurde bereits für eine andere Apple-ID bestätigt.",
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/data/attributes/password"
    }
  } ]
}
```

1.) It looks like the pointer is wrong - it should point to the email.

2.) The address may not be in use for an existing apple ID.

3.) Use a different email.

Comment: This helped enormously. Except they seemed to have disabled the `+` trick as of 018-12-13T00:48:25.750Z. Using a legitimately different email address worked. 

Also standard iTunes password requirements seem to apply (upper case, lower case, number, symbol), but it doesn't say that anywhere.

Comment: Thank you! I kept getting "This field is invalid" for the password field when I had security answer the same as question (except uppercase)

Comment: Feb 2019 and it's still an issue...  Thanks for this.  Didn't think to check the reply from the server.

Comment: Still an issue, can't find out what is going on:

Error on UI:An error has occurred. Try again later. Console:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 () JS Object: {logLevel: "ERROR", message: "API Response Error: CREATE_TESTER_RESPONSE", url: "https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/testers", stackTrace: "status code: 409 --- api correlation key: PI2HQV5VNZIPZLJTYFIKHNS5"}

Comment: Ah, so the console.log itself is not enough, might check Network/XHR.

Answer (score 3):

The reasons can be manifold. Due to the shocking engineering quality of *AppStoreConnect* you will have debug this yourself in case of an error.

Open the DevTools and watch the activity on the network:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "80fbaf6e-088a-4799-be70-1f8a657d97cb",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID",
    "title" : "The provided entity includes an attribute with an invalid value",
    "detail" : "MZDSExceptionMessage=Your password must have at least one capital letter., MZDSExceptionErrorCode=-21102",
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/data/attributes/password"
    }
  } ]
}
```

Sometimes it even points to the wrong control.

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "id" : "378775a9-1e5b-4e4a-bed9-4108f325b840",
    "status" : "409",
    "code" : "ENTITY_ERROR.ATTRIBUTE.INVALID",
    "title" : "The provided entity includes an attribute with an invalid value",
    "detail" : "MZDSExceptionMessage=The answer to your question cannot be the same as the question., MZDSExceptionErrorCode=-20156",
    "source" : {
      "pointer" : "/data/attributes/password"
    }
  } ]
}
```

The password requirements that worked for me:

- 2 digits
- 2 symbols ($$)
- 2 capital letters
- total length of 19

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Apple was having issues, because this morning I tried again (with the same exact details) and it worked.

Standard iTunes password requirements.

Comment: Not working for me today - same issue. Apparently Apple has issues somewhat often :(

Answer (score 0):

I have had my fair share of horrible experiences with Apple's sandbox environment, including this same issue. Moreover, you shouldn't trust their System Status page. I once spent 6 hours debugging IAP issues, but it turns out sandbox was down the entire time. It took them 7 hours to update the System Status page.

The "This field is invalid" issue shown by OP resolves itself in my experience. Just come back to it in a few hours.